# Load HTML ( including images ) through Ajax call ACP .NET MVC4

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to update a user list after some time interval for that I am calling a ajax call that send request to the action method that return a partial view. The returning result have HTML including images path but when I append HTML to specific location then no image displays (images do not load).

Here code is

```
var timer, delay = 60000;
timer=setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/SideMenuBar/GetOnlineUsers",
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function (data) {
  $('.chat_user_list').empty();
      $('.chat_user_list').append(data);
  });
}, delay);
```

How can I load images too through ajax call.

Comment: post some html from the partial view which includes the images

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the `.html()` method instead.

```
success: function (data) {
   $('.chat_user_list').html(data);
}
```

This method would update all the HTML elements inside the element specified and then add new content.

This way I think your images would get rendered.

Answer (score 0):

try to use image absolute path like this

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/my_image.jpg">
```

or check that your image path with respect to page in which your displaying ie your ajax code page is correct.